# IE: Divs move when window is resized too small

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-6

I'm almost finished with this site, and am just now trying to make it cross-browser. It works wonderfully in everything but IE6. I've fixed two of the problems it had, but am lost on the last one. The left sidebar moves right when the window is re-sized to something around 800px. The more you re-size, the more it moves, eventually covering up the content. This also seems to affect the header by shrinking it. The header is a small problem, but mostly just an annoyance.

I've tried a few fixes, but that did nothing. The only thread I could find that relates to this mentions that jQuery may be affecting it, but I have no jQuery set on that div. I'd appreciate any help that is given, as my deadline is approaching.

My HTML is:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="file:///C:/resources/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../_script/textShorten.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="file:///C:/Users/Matt/Desktop/Coding/Framed/framed_over.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="file:///C:/Users/Matt/Desktop/Coding/Framed/framed.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../_script/css.css" type="text/css" />
    <style type="text/css">
        _#wrapper   { height: 600px; }
        /* Photo Styles */
        #wrapper    { padding-right: 241px; }
        #sidebar        { right: 216px; }
        #infobar        { margin-right: -241px; }
        #content    { padding: 10px 20px; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header"><img src="../../_images/logo.png" alt=" " id="logo" /></div>

    <div id="wrapper">
<!-- START CONTENT -->
        <div id="content" class="column">
            <img src="-photo-images/thumb__zimmerman-thomas_01.jpg" class="framed" alt="Glasgow Necropolis 1">
            <img src="-photo-images/thumb__zimmerman-thomas_02.jpg" class="framed" alt="Glasgow Necropolis 2">
            <img src="-photo-images/thumb__zimmerman-thomas_03.jpg" class="framed" alt="Mother (II)">
        </div>
<!-- END CONTENT -->

        <div id="sidebar" class="column">
            <div id="top"><!-- EMPTY DIV --></div>
            <a href="index.html/">Home</a><br />
            <a href="archives.html/" id="none" >Archives</a><br />
            <a href="about.html">About Us</a><br />
            <a href="submit.html">Submit Your Work</a><br />
            <hr />
            <h2>January 2011</h2>
            <h3>Poets</h3>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="../-lit/valentina-cano.html">Valentina Cano</a></li>
                <li><a href="../-lit/ricky-garni.html">Ricky Garni</a></li>
                <li><a href="../-lit/kyle-hemmings.html">Kyle Hemmings</a></li>
                <li><a href="../-lit/paulus-kapteyn.html">Paulus Kapteyn</a></li>
                <li><a href="../-lit/tammy-ho.html">Tammy Ho Lai-Ming</a></li>
                <li><a href="../-lit/laura-lehew.html">Laura LeHew</a></li>
                <li><a href="../-lit/rhonda-maness.html">Rhonda Maness</a></li>
                <li><a href="../-lit/anita-mcqueen.html">Anita McQueen</a></li>
                <li><a href="../-lit/rodney-nelson.html">Rodney Nelson</a></li>
                <li><a href="../-lit/lise-phillips.html">Lise Phillips</a></li>
                <li><a href="../-lit/changming-yuan.html">Changming Yuan</a></li>
                <li><a href="../-lit/desmond-kon.html">Desmond Kon Zhicheng-Mingd&#233;</a></li>
            </ul>
            <br />
            <h3>Photographers</h3>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="../-photo/leila-fortier.html">Leila Fortier</a></li>
            <li><a href="../-photo/tammy-ho.html">Tammy Ho Lai-Ming</a></li>
            <li><a href="../-photo/allicia-strickland.html">Allicia Strickland</a></li>
            <li><a href="../-photo/jump-study.html">Jump Study Photography</a></li>
            <li><a href="../-photo/thomas-zimmerman.html">Thomas Zimmerman</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="infobar" class="column">
            <h1 id="author">Thomas Zimmerman</h1>
            <br />
<!-- Poem List -->
            <h4>Poems</h4>
            <ul id="submitList">
                <li>Glasgow Necropolis 1</li>
                <li>Glasgow Necropolis 2</li>
                <li>Mother (II)</li>
            </ul><br />
<!-- Issue Features -->
            <h4>Featured in Issues:</h4>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="../../2011-march/-photo/zimmerman-thomas.html/">March 2011</a></li>
            </ul>
<!-- Biography Start -->
            <h1 id="mark">Biography</h1>
            <p id="Bio">
                Thomas Zimmerman teaches English, directs the Writing Center, and edits three literary magazines at Washtenaw Community College, in Ann Arbor, MI. Photographs of his have appeared recently in the small magazines Bete Noire and Muscle &amp; Blood.
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">$("#infobar li").ellipsis();</script>    <!-- For FireFox -->
</body>
```

My CSS:

```
            /* Poetry Styles */
/*      #wrapper    { padding-right: 301px; }
        #sidebar        { right: 276px; }
        #infobar        { margin-right: -301px; }
        #content    { padding: 20px 50px; }
*/
        /* Photo Styles */
/*      #wrapper    { padding-right: 241px; }
        #sidebar        { right: 216px; }
        #infobar        { margin-right: -241px; }
        #content    { padding: 10px 20px; }
*/

        html,body,div,span,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,hr,p,a,abbr,acronym,address,big,del,em,img,
        small,strike,strong,sub,sup,ul,ol,fieldset,form,label,legend,
        table,caption,tbody,tfoot,thead,tr,th,td,optgroup,option
        {   margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0; outline: 0;
            text-align: left; vertical-align: middle;
            text-decoration: none; list-style: none; zoom: 1;
        }
/* Layout styles */
        body            { min-width: 900px; }
        div#wrapper { min-height: 600px; padding-left: 176px; padding-right: 301px; overflow: hidden !important; }
        div.column      { float: left; position: relative; padding-bottom: 20020px !important; margin-bottom: -20000px !important; }
        div#content { width: 100%; min-width: 400px; }
        div#sidebar     { right: 276px; margin-left: -100%; _left: 201px; }
        div#infobar     { margin-right: -301px; }
/* Layout Styles End */
        body
        {   background: rgb(20, 20, 20) url("../_images/bg_main.png");
            font-family: palitno linotype; color: white; font-size: 12px;
        }
        h1 { font-size: 20px; font-weight: normal; } h2 { font-size: 18px; font-weight: normal; } h3 { font-size: 16px; font-weight: normal; } h4 { font-size: 14px; font-weight: normal; } h5 { font-size: 12px; font-weight: normal; } h6 { font-size: 10px; font-weight: normal; }

        a                           {   color: white; position: relative; }
        a:link                  {   color: white; }
        a:visited               {   color: rgb(205, 205, 205); }
        a:hover             {   color: white; left: 3px; }
        div#content a:hover             {   left: 0; }
        a:active                {   color: white; }
        a[href="index.html"], a#none, a[href="about.html"], a[href="submit.html"]
        { font-size: 14px; }

        div#header
        {   height: 80px;
            background: rgb(27, 27, 27) url("../_images/bg_head.png") repeat-x;
            border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(136, 0, 0);
            overflow: hidden;
            padding: 10px 40px;
        }   img#logo { float: left; margin-right: 100px; display: inline; }

        div#content { padding: 20px 50px; text-align: center; }
            h1.poemTitle    { margin-bottom: 10px; text-align: left; }
            p.poem  { font-size: 14px; text-align: left; margin: 20px 0; line-height: 1.5; }

            div#content img { margin: 10px; border: 1px solid rgb(136, 0, 0); }

        div#sidebar
        {   width: 150px;                                           /* 175 - Padding-left, -right */
            background: rgb(27, 27, 27);
            border-right: 1px solid rgb(136, 0, 0);
            padding: 10px 5px 10px 20px;
            font-style: italic;
            background: transparent url("../_images/bg_sidebar.png") repeat-y;
            z-index: 0;
        }

        div#sidebar div#top
        {   width: 175px; height: 200px;
            position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0; z-index: -1;
            background: transparent url("../_images/bg_sidebar-top.png") no-repeat;
        }
        div#sidebar hr { margin: 8px -5px 8px -20px; border-top: 1px solid transparent; _border-top: 1px solid rgb(100, 0, 0); _border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(136, 0, 0); }
        div#sidebar h2 { font-size: 16px; position: relative; left: -8px; }
        div#sidebar h3 { font-size: 14px; }
        div#sidebar li { position: relative; left: 15px; text-indent: -7px; _text-indent: 0; }      /* Sets Wrap Indent. left=8+!'text-indent'; MAX 15px/-7px; */
        div#sidebar ul { font-style: normal; }

        div#infobar
        {   width: 160px;
            padding: 10px 20px;
            border-left: 1px solid rgb(136, 0, 0);
            background: rgb(27, 27, 27) url("../_images/bg_info.png") repeat-y;

        }       h1#author {  position: relative; left: -10px;}
                div#infobar h4  {  }
                div#infobar ul  { position: relative; left: 10px; }
                div#infobar li      { white-space: normal; overflow: hidden; -o-text-overflow: ellipsis; text-overflow: ellipsis; _margin-bottom: 5px; }
                h1#mark             {  position: relative; left: -10px; margin-top: 75px; margin-bottom: 10px; }
                p#Bio                   { max-height: 450px; white-space: normal; }
```

Comment: Microsoft is begging users not to use IE6 anymore. So ignore it. (just kidding :D)

Answer (score 2):

Simple; **dump support for IE 6.** Youtube and many other popular sites no longer support it, even Microsoft have abandoned it -- http://ie6countdown.com/

Comment: As tempting as that sounds, I'd rather not. At least for awhile. Even then, it would still be nice to know the answer in case something similar happens to show up for other browsers later. I am on the other so not even attempting support for IE5.5 >_> And it looks horrible in that.